# Unable to Connect to Samba Windows Printer

Tags: networking, printing, windows-10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 and gnome version 3.36

I need to print documents from my Ubuntu computer to a printer that is connected to my windows-10 computer on the same network and the same workgroup.

From the "new printer" dialog I click "windows printer via samba" and then I can see a "browse"  button. If I click the "browse" button nothing at all happens so instead of browsing I enter the direct path to my printer which is: smb://192.168.1.1/brother

I click "set authentication details now" and I enter my password and username and click "verify" but, again nothing happens.

So I click FORWARD and continue the set process hoping that it will work, but when I'm all done I am asked again for my credentials and then I get a "not authorized" error.

Note that I know I am entering the correct credentials because I am using these same credentials to access FILES via samba, and it works fine. My trouble is only when connecting to a PRINTER via samba.

In short:

1. why does nothing happen when I click BROWSE or VERIFY?
2. why am I getting "not authorized" if I'm entering the correct credentials?